# Garbage collector for managed c++

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, c++-cli, managed-c++

Normally in C++ with a pointer, if one were to create a dynamic object to pass into a function as a parameter, it would be done something like

```
Object *myObj = new Object;
someFunction(myObj);
delete myObj;
myObj = nullptr;
```

as opposed to

```
someFunction(new Object);
```

in order to not leak memory. Now suppose I am creating a garbage collected object; does the same rule still apply or would the garbage collector actually be able to delete a dynamically created object from memory created within the function call as shown below?

```
someFunction(gcnew Object);
```

Comment: It shouldn´t matter if the allocation is between () or not.

Comment: You no longer hqve to keep track of qll the objects you create with managed C++. Your C++/CLI objects will be collected  and destroyed as expected by the garbage collector even if your object in created in ().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    someFunction(gcnew Object);
```

Sure, that's fine.  The object won't survive for long, the next gen #0 collection is likely to destroy it if *someFunction* doesn't otherwise store the reference.  You can declare a variable but that's pointless, it will be removed by the jitter optimizer at runtime and you'll end up with the exact same code.

---

Pretty important to keep in mind however that the `delete` operator still exists in C++/CLI.  But does something *completely* different than it does in native C++.  It calls the IDisposable::Dispose() implementation method of a class.  This provides "deterministic destruction", like it does in C++.  Not quite the right word, it really is deterministic cleanup.  The interface is implemented by any managed class that stores an "expensive" operating system resource, the kind you don't want to have hanging around until the garbage collector cleans it up.

Boilerplate example is the System::Drawing::Bitmap class.  A very small class that is a wrapper for a big chunk of address space and (possibly) a file that is locked.  You want to make sure to dispose it when you don't need it anymore.  You could write such code like this:

```
void dosomething() {
    Bitmap^ bmp = gcnew Bitmap("foo.png");
    drawBitmap(bmp);
    delete bmp;
}
```

But that isn't correct code, it isn't exception-safe.  The *delete* operator call will be bypassed when *drawBitmap* throws an exception.  Not the end of the world btw, this doesn't actually cause a leak since the GC ultimately *will* clean it up.  Still, not pleasant, so the C++/CLI designers came up with an emulation for the native C++ RAII pattern, called "stack semantics" in C++/CLI:

```
void dosomething() {
    Bitmap bmp("foo.png");    // NOTE: no ^ hat
    drawBitmap(bmp);
}   // <=== bmp is disposed here
```

This should look familiar to any C++ programmer :)

Answer (score 0):

Managed object are all destroyed by the garbage collector when there is no more reference on it in your application.

In your situation here, if your function is not assigning your object somewhere else, it will be buffered to be garbage collected once your function returns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because a functioning garbage collector deletes dynamically allocated memory once the variable assigned to that memory goes out of scope. For example, in Java, you can say things like:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // do something.
    }
});
```

and the "ActionListener()" gets deleted once it goes out of scope. I'm only mentioning Java here because of its garbage collection properties and realize this is a C++ question. I'm just using it to explain a concept.